# Sort Categories for sj_k2_categories_ii Module in Page

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module, css, k2

i use this sj_k2_categories_ii module in my site
i make some menu with this module

how i can sort Categories by alphabet in my page
Categories sorted by module with k2 item ID

thanks

Comment: When your question is not getting enough attention, it is possible that volunteers need better details.  Are you able to include information such as what research you did, what relevant docs or tutorials you found, or any coding attempts you've made? If you are using someone else's extension, did you seek support directly from them?

Comment: @mickmackusa more information : i search any site about it - no one answer or speak about that and i cant find any other module work like this ( show just category in page )
i real all docs and tutorial from this module - no any option for sort by alphabet - im not try use custom code because i dont know how. the Main Support answer : we have no time for that you can do it for yourself or wait maybe someday we update it...

Comment: I can understand your frustration and I would help if I could, but I cannot.  The reason that I advised you to [edit] your question is because every time you edit your question, it is bumped to the top of the "active questions" list -- this will help new volunteers to find your post.  Please do not abuse this feature by adding non-relevant text into your question.  Please also capitalse all instances of the word `i` to `I` when you edit.

Comment: @mickmackusa My english isn't great. I know Joomla well... I can find any problem ... and I have many ideas... but if this problem needs code, then I can't fix it because my skill in php and html is not strong. I can't learn it as well because of corona... every where is closed.